# I have a user defined property in a class that does not get fired when I access the property via a repeat in an ASPX Page?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

First let me start off that I am new to angular and TS but have been working with senior members of our team that think that this code is fine (simple getter in javascript).... Thanks is advance for your help!! If more info is needed let me know.

So here is my record definition in TS......

```
export class LabDefExp {
    expID: number;
    labID: number;
    expTitle: string;
    expNum: string;
    numberOfExceptions: number;

    get displayFullExpTitle(): string {
        return '(' + this.expNum + ') ' + this.expTitle;
    }

    tags: secureNetReports.Tag[];
    constructor(labDefExp?: secureNetReports.LabDefExp) {
        if (labDefExp) {
            for (var fieldName in labDefExp) {
                this[fieldName] = labDefExp[fieldName];
            }
        }
    }
}

export class Tag {
    tagNum: string;
    traditionalIt: boolean;
    networkType: string;
    exceptionReason: string;
    modelType: string;
    deviceStatus: string;
    assetTypeId: string;

    get traditionalDisplay(): string { return this.traditionalIt ? 'Yes' : 'No'; }

    constructor(tag?: secureNetReports.Tag) {
        if (tag) {
            for (var fieldName in tag) {
                this[fieldName] = tag[fieldName];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the markup snippet...

```
   <accordion-group ng-repeat="exception in labDefRptSumm.exceptions" class="row" ng-show="exception.expTitle" ng-hide="!exception.expTitle">
          <accordion-heading>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
             <span ng-bind="exception.displayFullExpTitle"></span>
             ( <span class="badge" ng-class="vm.getBadgeClass(exception.numberOfExceptions)" ng-bind="exception.numberOfExceptions"></span> Devices)
           </div>
         </div>
              </accordion-heading>
         <div ng-repeat="tag in exception.tags" class="row" >                                    
           <table cats-table ng-hide="exception.tags == null" id="tags" ng-cloak>
                <thead>
                  <tr ng-show="exception.tags.length > 0">
                    <th>SecureNET Tag</th>
                    <th>Device Type</th>
                    <th>Status Name</th>
                    <th>Traditional Device?</th>
                    <th>Exception Reason</th>
                    <th>Network Type</th>
                     <th class="icons">
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="text-align: center" ng-show="exception.tags.length == 0">
                    <td>
                      <h4>No devices match your search criteria.</h4>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr ng-repeat="tag in exception.tags | filter:searchID">
                  <td ng-bind="tag.tagNum"></td>
                  <td ng-bind="tag.modelType"></td>
                  <td ng-init="sn=tag.deviceStatus">
                    <span class="badge"
                      ng-class="{ 'active': sn.indexOf('Active') == 0,
                                  'inactive': sn.indexOf('Inactive')==0,
                                  'parts-only': sn.indexOf('Parts Only')==0,
                                  'surplus': sn.indexOf('Surplus')==0,
                                  'return-visit': sn.indexOf('Return Visit')==0}"
                      ng-bind="tag.deviceStatus"></span>
                  </td>
                  <td ng-bind="tag.traditionalDisplay"></td>
                  <td ng-bind="tag.exceptionReason"></td>
                  <td ng-bind="tag.networkType"></td>
                 <td class="icons" nowrap>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="Import.aspx#/import/single/{{tag.assetTypeId}}/{{tag.tagNum}}">View</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

So when the call to properties displayFullExpTitle and traditionalDisplay are never fired if I go through dev tools (f12 on chrome) and set breakpoints? What am I missing that would cause this not to fire??

Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an angular filter instead of a getter function. I dont believe ng1 will call getters to update ng-bind values.

e.g I just wrote it in regular javascript

```
angular.module('something')
        .filter('displayFullExpTitle', [function(){
              return function(expDetail){
                        return '(' + expDetail.expNum + ') ' + expDetail.expTitle;
                    }
                }]);
```

then in ng-bind you can do

```
  <span ng-bind="exception | displayFullExpTitle"></span>
```